# Remove row from the model

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

There is a client (company). The client has contacts. You can link any number of contacts to a specific client.

Let's say you open the client you need. Then you select the contacts you need from the **ComboBox**, they are attached to this client.

Now the implementation is as follows, three tables in the database - contacts, clients and assignment, the third contains the contact id and the company id - everything is simple. There is also a *QSqlQueryModel* assignment_contacts model - I inserted it into the **ComboBox**. Her code:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT id, fullName FROM contacts WHERE contacts.rowid NOT IN (SELECT contactId FROM assignment WHERE companyId = :nextId);");
query.bindValue(":nextId", nextId);
query.exec();
assignment_contacts->setQuery(std::move(query));
```

Roughly speaking, this model stores those contacts that are not yet tied to the selected company. The added contacts are displayed on the screen under the combo. Now, by clicking on the combobox element, a connection is added to the database and the assignment_contacts model is subsequently updated. That is, everything works properly, but I do not like the fact that it is added to the database before pressing the "save" button:

[image]

This confuses managers, they added contacts, clicked on cancel - and the contacts are already in the database. Plus, if another manager opens the same company, she will have these linked contacts, although the first manager has not clicked "save" yet. In general, I decided to implement a similar thing, only WITHOUT adding to the database, but storing the added id's in some list, and when you press the save button, add the links to the database. I started doing it, everything goes according to plan, but I can’t implement the logic with updating the model :-)

That is, you need to click on the name of the contact in the combo, and write the id of this contact to the list, with the subsequent removal of this entry from the model.
I got the idea to make a *QSortFilterProxyMode*l. I did it, put my original *QSqlQueryModel* in **->sourceModel**, tried to delete rows from it - unsuccessfully, as with deleting from *QSqlQueryModel*, but it's not surprising. What should I do, what model can I use?

Comment: Why not simply re-execute query and set it to a model again after edits are saved

Comment: @ALexey, I'm trying to ensure that the data in the database is not updated, which means there is nowhere to make a request. It is necessary to change the existing model, without any connection with the database.

Comment: Oh, I've got it. Then I'd advise you to use QComboBox without model and populate it with data explicitly with results of executed QSqlQuery. In this case you would be able to remove required items in it, while 'linking contacts routine is performed.

Comment: Another case, if you really want to use a model, make own model class derived from QAbstractListModel, for example, set it to QComboBox, populate with QSqlQuery results and process addings and removals of it's items by the way.

Comment: @Alexey, Now I made a similar logic using QStandardItemModel, filling it in a loop using an SQL query, and when a contact is selected, saving all the id of the saved contacts in QList<String>. When you click the save button, also using a loop, id from this list is added to assignment in the database. A rather cumbersome code with a large number of cycles, but I did not find another solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have one list of contacts in model and another list of selected contact ids. When contact is selected, it's id is appended to the list of selected contacts, and itself is removed from model's underlying list if available contacts. When data is saved you cycle through the list of selected contact ids and inserts rows to a data table. So it conforms to your needs.

Comment: There is one more solution, that allows to fill a contact list model, without removing them from list. It requires to implement a QSortFilterProxyModel derived class, that would use a contact list model as the source model and a list of the selected contact ids to filter the available contact list shown in QComboBox. Then a contact list model can be a QSqlQueryModel

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're trying to handle it in the model.

User input in a dialog is data which is subject to change - that's why it's presented in a dialog. You're not saving every individual digit of the phone number back to the model, when the user is editing a phone number in the view. Data, while it's being edited, belongs in the view. "Save" updates the model with the view. "Cancel" resets the view to the model.

Therefore, the list of contact changes should also be temporarily stored in the view, until it's saved.

Comment: I understand this, and this is what I want to achieve. Store the id of the assigned contacts in a certain list, and after clicking on "Save" - ​​insert the data into the database. My problem is that the list of contacts that are NOT yet owned by the selected company was being obtained by QSqlQuery, excluding all contacts that are already associated with it. Without adding to the DB by another solution, I see deleting data from the model, and that's exactly what doesn't work. It is my problem. You need a tabular model populated with SQL queries, but which can be edited by deleting rows.

Comment: I suspect your use of "query" might be a clue, but I can't put my finger on it. An SQL query is a request to the database. The contact list is the **result** of the query. Once you have the contacts, the query has finished. The name `QSqlQueryModel` is a related hint. I'd expect `ContactsModel`. The fact that you used Qt and SQL is an implementation detail, and an important part of models is that they should **hide** details.

Comment: The task itself is not difficult. It seems like everything is in reality - you fill in the model using an SQL query, then you work exclusively with the model. You delete contact - you delete a line from model. Added a contact - added a line to the model, and then load the new model into the database, for example. But I don’t understand which model I should work with, or even switch from models to something else.